# Display specific shipping class below "Add to cart" on Woocommerce single products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

In Woocommerce I would like to display a specific shipping class, on a single product pages

**For Example:** If a product has a "Pickup Only" shipping class, I'd like that to be visible just below the "Add to Cart" button (all other classes do not need to be displayed).

How can I display specific shipping class below "Add to cart" on Woocommerce single product pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated** - The following code will display the shipping class name, in single product pages, below add to cart button, only when it is "Pickup Only":

```
// On single product pages
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','display_specific_shipping_class', 35 ); 
function display_specific_shipping_class(){
    global $product;

    // HERE define your targeted shipping class name
    $defined_shipping_class = "Pickup Only";

    $product_shipping_class = $product->get_shipping_class();

    // Get the product shipping class term name
    $term_name = get_term_by( 'slug', $product_shipping_class, 'product_shipping_class' )->name;

    if( $term_name == $defined_shipping_class ){
        echo '<p class="product-shipping-class">' . $term_name . '</p>';
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.